# Custom login doesn't work properly

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, wp-login-form, nonce, authorization

I've a made a plugin which generates a login form, by using a shortcode. The login works, however, inside the dashboard I've noticed that the forms submits don't work properly. For example, the profile update doesn't work, namely, when the ***Save*** button is pressed, the page is reloaded, but the changes are not stored into the database. 
Here is the code:

```
function login_validation( $username, $password )  {
    global $reg_errors;
    $reg_errors = new WP_Error;

    if ( empty( $username ) && !empty( $password ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add('field', 'The username field is empty');
    } else if ( !empty( $username ) && empty( $password ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add('field', 'The password field is empty');
    } else if ( empty( $username ) && empty( $password ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add('field', 'The fields are empty');
    } else if ( !username_exists( $username ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add('user_name', 'Sorry, that username doesn\'t exists!');
    } else if ( !validate_username( $username ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add('username_invalid', 'Sorry, the username you entered is not valid');
    }

    if ( is_wp_error( $reg_errors ) ) {

        foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error ) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger message-box">';
            echo '<strong>ERROR</strong>: ';
            echo $error . '<br/>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}

function custom_login() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user($_POST['username']);
        $login_data['user_password'] = esc_attr($_POST['password']);

        $user = wp_signon( $login_data, false );

        if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
            echo $user->get_error_message();
        } else {
            wp_clear_auth_cookie();
            do_action('wp_login', $user->ID);
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
            $redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

function login_form() { ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="username">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="password">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <?php wp_nonce_field('wp_login'); ?>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"/>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php }

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );

/*
 * Remove the response error messages from the header
 */
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_error_messages', 10, 3 );
function change_error_messages( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( 'default' !== $domain )
        return $translation;

    if ( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' == $text )
        return '';

    if ( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password field is empty.' == $text )
        return '';

    if ( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href=\"%s\" title=\"Password Lost and Found\">Lost your password</a>?' == $text )
        return '';

    return $translation;    
}

// The callback function that will replace
function custom_login_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    custom_login_function();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// Register a new shortcode: [cr_custom_login]
add_shortcode('cr_custom_login', 'custom_login_shortcode');
```

If I disable this plugin, everything works. I think the problem is that some sort of validation doesn't take place. Maybe the `nonce` field? Am I right? How can I fix it? 
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
As the user @Krzysiek Dróżdż suggested, I updated the `custom_login` function as follows:

```
function custom_login() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user($_POST['username']);
        $login_data['user_password'] = esc_attr($_POST['password']);
        $nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];

        $user = wp_signon( $login_data, false );

        global $user_ID;
        // Check whether the user is already logged in
        if ( !$user_ID ) {
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'wp_login' ) ) {
                // die( 'Security check' );
                exit;
            } else {
                if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
                    echo $user->get_error_message();
                } else {
                    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                    do_action('wp_login', $user->ID);
                    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
                    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
                    $redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem seems to be fixed.
What if I want to use another type of check instead of `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`?

Comment: You're pretty brave to try the login process every time there is a $_POST['submit'] available. Any form could set that. Also sending the form to current address isn't very good idea. And worse, you don't check that nonce anywhere... Why don't you use wp_login_form() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution:

```
function custom_login() {
    if(!empty($_POST['user_login']) && !empty($_POST['user_pass'])){
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user($_POST['user_login']);
        $login_data['user_password'] = esc_attr($_POST['user_pass']);
        $login_data['rememberme'] = true;
        $nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];

        $user = wp_signon( $login_data, false );

        global $user_ID;
        // Check whether the user is already logged in and the nonce is verified
        if ( !$user_ID && !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'wp_login' ) ) {
            exit;
        } else {
            if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
                echo $user->get_error_message();
            } else {
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                do_action('wp_login', $user->ID);
                wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
                wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```